# Leaflet Marker is Not Displaying in Website - Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, leaflet, codeigniter-3, qgis

I'm new in programming and i make this one. But there is a problem when i tried to applied the leaflet into web using codeigniter, my markers are not showing.

Here is my javascript for the marker:

```
function style_point_1_0() {
        return {
            pane: 'pane_point_1',
    rotationAngle: 0.0,
    rotationOrigin: 'center center',
    icon: L.icon({
        iconUrl: '<?php echo base_url();?>layout/leaflet/markers/blue-marker.svg',
        iconSize: [64.6, 64.6]
    }),
        }
    }
    map.createPane('pane_point_1');
    map.getPane('pane_point_1').style.zIndex = 401;
    map.getPane('pane_point_1').style['mix-blend-mode'] = 'normal';
    var layer_point_1 = new L.geoJson(json_point_1, {
        attribution: '<a href="">asd</a>',
        pane: 'pane_point_1',
        onEachFeature: pop_point_1,
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            var context = {
                feature: feature,
                variables: {}
            };
            return L.marker(latlng, style_point_1_0(feature));
        },
    });
```

Script that load json data :

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>layout/leaflet/data/point_1.js"></script>
```

Before that i found this source and im little confuse how to execute my code.

Source - [Leaflet - Markers not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45471211/leaflet-markers-not-showing)

Hope someone can help to solve this problem, Thank you.

Comment: I think you are confused between server side and client side execution. PHP executes on the server. Javascript executes in the browser. Therefore, your php echo inside your Javascript will never work because the browser doesn't understand how to execute PHP code.

Comment: so what im supposed to do now ? cause im stuck there with that problem

Comment: Well, assuming you have everything else set up correctly. Try changing your iconUrl property to an actually http endpoint. For example, "http:// yourwebsite/layout/leaflet/markers/blue-marker.svg".

Comment: my iconUrl was correct, but my marker still not shown to the view.

Comment: You haven't given me enough to know what is happening. But, I'm guessing your script is just not executing when your page loads. Your web page needs to call your javascript function once it's done loading. The bit that you provided just defines the javascript function, but it's never called to execute.

Comment: So i'll tell you that i have a marker on my page site, but there is a problem why my marker still not showing up. I dont know where is my fault in my code, and i think iconUrl was called correctly.

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors in your browser console?

Comment: nope. But it was solved.
i just redeclared with new var, and added some .addTo(map) in my code.